# use-package hook in to multiple modes

Tags: use-package

How can I tell this config to also activate git-auto-commit-mode
mode for the `js-mode` in addition to `fundamental-mode`

```
(use-package git-auto-commit-mode
  :hook
  (fundamental-mode . git-auto-commit-mode)
  :custom
  (gac-ask-for-summary-p t))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual (section 4.13), the car of the `:hook` form can be a list.  So

```
(use-package git-auto-commit-mode
  :hook
  ((fundamental-mode js-mode) . git-auto-commit-mode)
  :custom
  (gac-ask-for-summary-p t))
```

should do the job.